# Joining up to 3 values in an array in a loop

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I am trying to run some logical tests and matching a list of strings against a database but need help with the array I have.

## the Problem

I have an array:

```
$myArray =
array([0] (
   array [0] ([0] A, [1] B, [2] C, [3] H)
   array [1] ([0] A, [1] D, [2] G, [3] H, [4] L)
   array [2] ([0] D, [1] Z, [2] J, [3] K, [4] O, [5] X)
)
array([1] (
   array [2] ([0] F, [1] Y, [2] W, [3] H, [4] L)
)
array([2] (
   array [0] ([0] O, [1] T, [2] C, [4] O, [5] X)
   array [1] ([0] U, [1] E, [2] E, [3] D)
))
```

I am trying to test the strings in this array against a list that combines 1, 2 and 3 strings combined with '_' in a table. 
Example: A or A_B or A_B_C

## Variables and Constants

- The array length can vary in each of the second dimension of the array
- Strings can be repeated several times and it has no bearing on the logic
- The constant however is that the test to combine two strings or three strings is always sequential (e.g. always A_B or A_B_C and not A_D or A_D_J if that makes sense)
- The sequence moves by one letter each time e.g. first test (A_B_C, A_B and A), then test (B_C_D, B_C and B), then (C_D_E etc...)
- When the array has insufficient strings to continue testing 2 or 3 combined words, then the test should just run on 1 string

## What I am trying to do and desired outcome

I need help with the array syntax to help me build the code into a 3 level logical argument in a loop

something like this:
IF A_B_C exists in myTable do something 
ELSE IF A_B exists do something else 
ELSE IF A exists do yet another thing 
ELSE return blank

I can't quite figure out however how to manipulate the above array so as to arrive at variables

```
$firstTest = 'A_B_C'; <br>
$secondTest = 'A_B'; <br>
$thirdTest = 'A'; <br>
```

(I can get thirdTest)

## What I tried

through receiving some useful help on other array questions, I tried passing the $myArray through a foreach loop as follow:

```
foreach ($myArray as $newArray) {
$i = 0;
$j = $i++;

foreach($newArray as $key=>$val) {
    $impArray = array($val[$i],$val[$j]);
    echo implode('_', $impArray);
}
}
```

However this takes the first string of each first level array.

EDIT:

I have been experimenting with array_slice and do while and can almost get there but the pattern does not quite follow a 3x string combination; instead, it increases from 3 strings to 4 strings, to 5 strings etc... and I do not know why.

Here is my latest attempts:

```
foreach ($myArray as $newArray => $val) {
    $x = 0;
    $z = 3;
    $route = array();
    
    do  {

        $route = array_slice($val, $x , $z);
        $imp_route = implode('_', $route);
        echo $imp_route;
        $x++;
        $z++;
    } while ( $z <= count($val));
}
```

Comment: Your examples don't seem to line up with the `$myArray` you provided at the beginning. Can you please make sure your examples under **Variables and Constants** match the given `$myArray`? For example, I don't see any set that would yield a `B_C_D` combination.

Comment: yes I am trying to be as clear as possible here in the V&C. I refer to A_B_C for the purpose of showing these are sequential. But if you wish, the sequence must run, A_B_C, B_C_H and then on array [1] A_D_G, D_G_H etc...

Comment: That helps, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there's a fancier way to do it, but this way makes it clear what you're trying to accomplish:

```
foreach ($myArray as $newArray) {
    foreach ($newArray as $valuesArray) {
        for ($i=0; $i<count($valuesArray); $i++) {
            // A_B_C
            if (isset($valuesArray[$i+2])) {
                echo $valuesArray[$i] . '_' . $valuesArray[$i+1] . '_' . $valuesArray[$i+2];
            }
            // A_B
            if (isset($valuesArray[$i+1])) {
                echo $valuesArray[$i] . '_' . $valuesArray[$i+1];
            }
            // A
            echo $valuesArray[$i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this code, it almost works but it breaks down each strings in $myArray into individual letters. I can't quite understand why it is doing this from the code though?

Comment: Also, I have been experimenting with do while and array_slice and can almost get there but instead of looping through as follow A_B_C, B_C_D etc..., it goes A_B_C, B_C_D_E, C_D_E_F etc... and I am not quite sure why. But if you have comments/ suggestions, that would hugely help me learn

Comment: all of the strings in the example you posted are individual letters

Comment: @Jacob Your first comment makes it sound like we've got one too many layers of looping. Try it without the inner `foreach`